# C++ iostream encoding?

Tags: c++

I have an `input.txt` and an `output.txt`, obviously I generate the `output.txt`, which for now is to write the exact same thing out, but it does not do that because of a possible encoding(?) error.

Here are pictures of the input and output:

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

My code looks like this:

Menu.cpp:

```
void Menu::kiir(){
    ofstream myfile("output.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        myfile << sakk.toString();
    }
}
```

The `toString()` method in `sakktabla.cpp`:

```
string sakktabla::toString(){
    std::string eredmeny="";
    int x = this->x;
    int y = this->y;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
            eredmeny += (int)getValue(i, j);
        }
        eredmeny += "\n";
    }
    return eredmeny;
}
```

The `getValue()` method:

```
int sakktabla::getValue(int x, int y){
    return this->_vec[x][y];
}
```

Comment: You wrote numbers to the file, not characters. There's no encoding issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you're ingesting, but you seem to be:

- reading character input such as the character `'2'`;
- converting that to integer input, i.e. the integer `2`;
- outputting that integer, here producing an ASCII character with value `2`.

Possibly the confusion is that [`std::string::operator+=`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/) doesn't do any sort of conversion.

You possibly want:

```
eredmeny += std::to_string(getValue(i, j));
```

[`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) converts a bunch of numeric types to their human-readable string counterparts.